# Internet completely messed up after closing VPN

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, dns, routing

I use a VPN from time to time that lets me access certain resources (eg. music sites) that would normally be restricted to the US. I recently got an account for PrivateInternetAccess which works fine unless I turn off the VPN -- this completely screws up my internet connection on my OSX machine. Comparatively using my work VPN has no such issues, and other computer on my network are not affected.

What happens is that most sites will simply fail to load, whereas a few (like google) will load (slowly) but even when loading show that there is some content that will continue to try and load until a timeout occurs. Pinging the sites works fine and a traceroute completes with (as far as I can tell) no weird occurrences in the route.

Things I've tried:

- Restart
- Flush DNS
- Different Browsers
- Flush routing tables
- Unplug/replug network cable

None seem to work. I think it's safe to say I won't use this VPN anymore but my internet connection is still acting weird and I'd like to get it back to normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Next time this happens, check the content of /etc/resolv.conf and the routing table, **before** restoring the status quo, and post them here, if you need help troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

After a bit more testing it seems I've resolved my issue by restarting my router. I'm still not sure exactly what was the cause of it all, and considering other computers that were connected through the router were not having any issues the resolution seems odd to me. Possibly my router caches routes per-client? Very odd.